# Откуда $arResult берет значении массива?

Tags: php, битрикс

Хотелось бы узнать, откуда в `$arResult` берут значении массива в компоненте?

К примеру если смотрим компонент новостей через `var_dump` или `print_r`, то в массиве `$arResult` можно встретить одни ключи и значения, а в компоненте слайдеров другие ключи и значения.

Comment: Не кажется что стоит прибавить кода, примеров? Или искать должны сами?

Answer (score 1):

Массив $arResult заполняется непосредственно компонентом и может заполняться/модифицироваться файлом result_modifier.php в шаблоне компонента. Разработчик компонента сам определяет, какие ключи и значения заносить в этот массив. Как правило, исходя из того, какие данные по мнению автора компонента нужны будут шаблону компонента для отображения.

Answer (score 1):

У каждого компонента в Bitrix, есть файл component.php или class.php, в данном файле исходя из логики работы компонента формируется массив $arResult, который отправляется в шаблон компонента.

Более подробную информацию вы найдете в официальной документации https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04565&LESSON_PATH=3913.4565